# Custom PHP/Apache2 Installer with web application

Tags: php, apache, web

I want to make custom php/apache2 installer including my web application for distribution. So for example user downloads the one click installer and he will have installed php/apache2 and web application. And all he have to do is go to localhost. (The best thing would be double click then shortcut icon just to go to localhost in browser, but check that apache is running)

What is the proper way to do it? Any tips, easy tip of doing it?

p.s. for all popular os Mac OS, Win, and Linux/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I'd ship a Virtual Machine with the application, and supporting platform, installed and ready to go. [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is well supported and would be a good place to start.

Good luck,

Anthony.

Answer (score 0):

Latest PHP version has a [webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) included and with SQLite, all you need is to start PHP WebServer, maybe it could help to make a lightweight installation.